# ESP32 unable to extract string from string based on Regexp mask

Tags: regex, esp32

have done a lot of research but cannot find proper formating for Regexp mask in order to extract a string from another string.

Suppose I have the following string:
"The quick brown fox ABC3D97 jumps over the lazy wolf"
I need to extract the "ABC3D97" based on the mask: /[A-Z]{3}\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{2}/ but I just cannot find the proper syntax as the one above and variations of it return no match.

My test code is as below:

```
#include <Regexp.h>

void setup ()    {
  Serial.begin (115200);

  // match state object
  MatchState ms;

  // what we are searching (the target)
  char buf [100] = "The quick brown fox ABC3D97 jumps over the lazy wolf";
  ms.Target (buf);  // set its address
  Serial.println (buf);

  char result = ms.Match ("d{3}");   <-- returns no match. 
  
  if (result > 0)    {
    Serial.print ("Found match at: ");
    int matchStart = ms.MatchStart;
    int matchLength = ms.MatchLength;
    Serial.println (matchStart);        // 16 in this case     
    Serial.print ("Match length: ");
    Serial.println (matchLength);       // 3 in this case
    String text = String(buf);
    Serial.println(text.substring(matchStart,matchStart+matchLength));
    }
  else
    Serial.println ("No match.");
    
}  // end of setup  

void loop () {}
```

Assistance welcome.

Comment: If you use `regex.h`, you are using POSIX BRE, so use `ms.Match ("[A-Z]\\{3\\}[0-9][A-Z][0-9]\\{2\\}")`

Comment: Hi Wiktor, just adding char result = ms.Match ("[A-Z]\\{3\\}[0-9][A-Z][0-9]\\{2\\}"); returns NoMatch, but I am using #include <Regexp.h>, if I change to #include <Regex.h> the compiler complains of: 'MatchState' was not declared in this scope. Thanks

Comment: `d{3}` means match `ddd`, which doesn't appear in your test string, so the code in your question is working correctly if it doesn't find a match.

Comment: ronkey, yes, I know that, that is what is working in NodeRed so I was trying the same syntax. In fact I did include (ABC3D972) before for this test but did not work. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The library you're using appears to be [Nick Gammon's port of regular expression functionality from LUA](https://github.com/nickgammon/Regexp).

LUA's regular expressions use a different syntax than other commonly used regular expressions. The README for the library gives a link to the [documentation on LUA's regular expressions](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1).

LUA uses `%` rather than `\` for character classes, so `\d` needs to be written as `%d`. This library also doesn't support the `{number}` syntax to specify the number of matches. You have to repeat the match characters.

According to the documentation, the match string should be:

```
[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]%d[A-Z]%d%d
```

and not

```
[A-Z]{3}\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{2}
```

Comment: Dear romkey, worked like a dream, I am on this problem half of the day! Thanks a lot for your time and knowledge. Keep well, Paulo

Comment: @PauloBorges please accept answers that solve problems. This allows other people with similar problems to see that an answer worked.

Comment: I tried that already when you helped me last time. When I do that there is a pop up message that says I need 15 reputations to mark an answer as solving the problem. It does not make sense, when the answer solves the problem it should not matter the "reputation" of the one declaring problem solved. Sorry for that, will try to get some "reputation" in order to mark useful supports as yours properly. Thanks again.